# Torsion units in the group algebra $FG$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, vector-spaces

Let us denote by $FG$ group algebra of a group $G$ over the field $F$. Assume that $\alpha\in FG$ satisfies $\alpha^n=1$ for some $n$. Then, the commutative finite dimensional algebra $F[\alpha]$ can be expressed as a direct sum of isomorphic copies $$F[\alpha]\cong Fe_1\oplus Fe_2\oplus\cdots\oplus Fe_t$$ in which $1=e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_t$, and $e_ie_j=\delta_{ij}e_j$ with $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. Is it right? I do not make sure such an argument. I would like to ask when it is true. I think it holds when $F=\mathbb{C}$ is the field of complex numbers. For instance, $\mathbb{C}[\alpha]$ is isomorphic $\mathbb{C}[X]/\langle f(x)\rangle$, the factor ring of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[X]$ by a polynomial $f(X)$ being a divisor of $X^n-1$. However, I also make sure it is right.

Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to write $F[\alpha]\cong$ rather than $FG\cong$?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it wrong. Excuse me, I have just rewritten it. @rschwieb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a $p$ group and $F$ is the field of $p$ elements ($p$ a prime number) then $F[G]$ is local, and the only idempotents are $0$ and $1$. If what you're saying were true, then you could only have one nonzero idempotent element for your $e_i$'s, making it one dimensional.

But you can choose $G$ and $\alpha$ so that $F[\alpha]$ is more than $1$ dimensional.  For example, you could have started with $G$ the cyclic group of order $p$, and then any element of $G$ works for $\alpha$.

Comment: Excuse me, I write it wrong. The thing I want is $F[\alpha]$, not $FG$. Please make it clear and consider it again. I also want to know clearly about idempotents. For instance, when do idempotents exist to decompose such $F[\alpha]$?

Comment: @TranNamSon What I've written does not hinge on your edit: i wrote the answer assuming what you edited in was what you meant.

Comment: @TranNamSon Well, when $\alpha^n=1$, you know you're just dealing with a cyclic group of some order dividing $n$.  You may as well assume $G$ is that cyclic group. In that case we know for sure $F[G]$ is semisimple if the characteristic of $F$ is zero or does not divide $|G|$.  That would make the group algebra a direct sum of $|G|$ copies of $F$, and hence have the decomposition you seek.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you so much @rschwieb. On the other hand, do you know any of the existence of idempotents in an algebra and the expression into a direct sum of primitive orthogonal idempotents?

Comment: @TranNamSon There is a standard result that a ring admits such a decomposition into orthogonal *local* idempotents iff and only if it is a semiperfect ring.  A local idempotent is one such that $eRe$ is a local ring, and that's strictly stronger than a *primitive* idempotent.

Comment: Yes, I understand and I gratefully thank @rschwieb. Best wishes to you and your family.